# Is it a standard practice to explicitly exclude dependencies?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j2

for example, in my `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

for some reasons, the dependencies graph is like:

[image]

So, there is a conflicting `log4j-api` (2.7 vs 2.15).

To fix this, I can explicitly exclude `log4j-api` in the `log4j-core` dependency. However, is this actually a standard practice since the `log4j-api 2.15.0` will always be used anyway due to dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

So first if a app is using log4j-api in version 2.7 this has even not being upgrade for 5 years apart from that I suppose that the api has not being changed (which the api part implies) so you should or could only replace the implementation (log4j-core) and use the more recent version. You can exclude dependencies via the exclusions like this.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This can also being done in `dependencyManagement` which is even better...In such I would not exclude the api here...

Comment: I know the above can be done...just want to know which is the correct way: explicitly excluding it or let dependency management handle it?